# A 4-dimensional orange peeling problem: Can you disassemble a 4D hypersphere into a 3D object?

Tags: real-analysis, dimension-theory-analysis

**Where I am coming from:** Similar to if you peel an orange, you cannot project the 2D surface of the Earth onto a 2D plane *without curves*. However, I’m pretty sure it’s possible to take the circumference of a circle and unwrap it into a line.

---

**The following is my question broken down:**

> 1. Why is the transformation from a circular line that is 1D to a 1D line "easy"?
> 2. Is there a word for this?
> 3. Why is the transformation from a surface wrapped around a sphere (2D) to a (2D) plane *without curves* "hard"?
> 4. Does this persist with $n$-dimensional hyperspheres to other $n$ dimensional elements?

I can't seem to describe my question properly; but when I mean elements, I want to refer to the basic element, if there is one, of an $n$th-dimension. For example, the "basic" element of the first dimension would be a line, and the second would be plane. So would it be right to extrapolate and assume that the "basic" element of the third dimension would be a cube?

> 5. How would you describe a "*basic*" element of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I know answers for this might include "it depends on the situation/it can be anything depending on context," so here it is: I would like a rigorous definition that connects a line, the mesh (I tried learning topology) of a square and a cube. I would also like if this could be extrapolated to higher dimensions so that my questions before make sense.

---

#### Question

> Q. Is there a word for the difficulty of a mapping from a hyperspherical object in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a "*basic*" element of $\mathbb{R}^n$; by which I hope to refer to a mesh that is defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with dimensions defined by independent perpendicular lines? **Does this difficulty persist/change in higher dimensions?**

**Restriction:** The type of transformations I described above should not involve infinite slices.

That is the sloppiest question I asked, so I apologize. I am not a specialist in mathematics such as topology, so an answer in layman's terms is what I am looking for. However, I can work with answers involving calculus and possibly a little bit of elementary real-analysis.

Comment: You can project the surface of the Earth onto a plane just fine. There are many ways to do it.

Comment: I meant to ask projecting it perfectly onto a plane with no curves. I will edit the question for clarity.

Comment: @Servaes You can't do that if you want to locally preserve distances (but you can do it with a circle on a line). I think is clear what OP is talking about even if it's not written in a precise form.

Comment: If I were trying to prove this is impossible, I would probably try to show that a triangle in the sphere cannot be flattened, preserving lengths and area. The circle flattening doesn't have to preserve area, just length. That would be my initial intuition.

Comment: So in 4D, you would have to preserve distance, area, and volume? So it is "harder" for such a projection. How would you describe this mathematically? I assume the proof would center around the notion of distance, area, and volume (I don't know of any word that generalizes these three, however).

Comment: @jjagmath It would help if the OP specified the properties such a 'projection' should have. I understand that OP is not versed in (differential) geometry but the very process of trying to specify this should be very instructive.

Comment: Adding to what @Servaes said, one can cut up the sphere into infinitely many lines, one for each "longitudinal" line, and then flatten each line without any "curves". I am assuming OP would like to restrict this, but it isn't clear to me which precise restriction they desire. Perhaps only a finite number of cuts can be made? Or perhaps one cannot make a cut that results in a strip with $0$ length/area/volume etc.

Comment: @Carlyle, I think you misunderstood the question. I wanted a flat projection from a $n$-dimensional sphere to an $n$-dimensional "basic" element (whatever that may be, hopefully defining an $n$-cube). So a projection from the surface of a sphere to a line is not what I was looking for.

Comment: @sreysus perhaps, but I think you may have misunderstood my comment as well, what I am describing is peeling the orange by making infinitely many vertical cuts to end up with a bunch of orange peel "hairs" that are joined only at the bottom, and then laying them all flat on the table, which is $2$ dimensional, you can lay them flat without curving simply because each of them is a line segment, but together they still make up the entire peel

Comment: @Carlyle I apologize, I will edit the question.

Comment: @sreysus Thank you for the clarification, this does in fact make it more clear, I don't think a plane and a cube etc is the most natural generalisation, an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ usually translates to a disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and considering your objects are the boundaries of these generalisations, they seem the natural to me, but that is just my opinion

Comment: We don't need 4D to talk about this. It's actually not possible to truly peel an orange this way - the pieces you carve out will not and cannot lie perfectly flat, only nearly flat. In other words, there is no isometry from a neighborhood on a sphere to the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the qualitative intuition behind the question: The circle ($1$-sphere) is *intrinsically flat*, i.e., *locally isometric to the Euclidean line*. By contrast, if $n > 1$ then the $n$-sphere is not locally isometric to Euclidean $n$-space, essentially *because Gaussian curvature* and the [*Theorema Egregium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium).